# What are some use cases for retaining JSX after transpiling a tsx file?

Tags: typescript, jsx

As I work through another issue, I came to read [the Typescript documentation on the JSX option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html).

Some options convert JSX and some dont.

I'm trying to understand why anyone would need to retain JSX in transpiled files. I know that you can post-process the transpiled files with babel to handle the JSX... but why?

Are there some transformations that can be done on JSX that Typescript doesn't support? Is there some need to retain JSX for React Native (since there's a dedicated `react-native` option that seems identical to `react`, but for the generated files' extensions)?

Answer (score 1):

[This issue thread](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8529) lists a few reasons, including the possibility of runtime assertions and breaking JSX changes that the TS transpiler might be behind on. From my own experience, transpiling away the TypeScript and then running the result (with JSX) into Babel as part of a larger build is conceptually more convenient, though I don't know if there's any performance benefit. [Another example](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/735) mentions wanting to transform JSX on the entirety of the code rather than having TS work on just its parts. Developers on codebases with a mix of build systems (personally I've been in repos with TS, Webpack, Babel, AND Rollup!) have to just choose which tool they want to use when there's overlap in functionality, and I've usually chosen to let Babel do the React work due to Babel's longer history with the Facebook ecosystem.

As to the second question, per [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html) and [this PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13636), the `react-native` option outputs the `js` extension rather than `jsx`, and is otherwise equivalent to `preserve`.